# How to Apply Webkit-input-placeholder only when assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color: #9A1B1E;}
```

I want to use this with an ID of some sort to apply it to some elements, not the entire page. I can't seem to be able to put this under a group.

At least add it as a class using jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
.class::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #9A1B1E;
}

#id::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #9A1B1E;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/7tL7W/1/)